# Appium 1.2.2 - Desired capabilities required but not provided

Tags: android, cordova, automated-tests, appium

I'm trying to test my phonegap application with Appium@1.2.2 on my Nexus7@4.4.4. The app launches correctly but when I try to set the context to `WEBVIEW` Appium crashes with following error:

```
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: The following desired   capabilities are required, but were not provided: platformName, deviceName
```

Ok, the message is clear but what confuses me, is that I've already set those capabilities via `java-client`

```
[...]
    capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "Appium");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Nexus 7");
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "my.app.package");

    driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub"), capabilities);

[...]
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing a Phonegap app, right? Well, you need to use the `Selendroid` engine then, the (default) UiAutomator engine doesn't support Webviews.

Excerpt from [Appium documentation](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#running-your-test-app-with-appium-(android-devices-%3C-4.2,-and-hybrid-tests)):

> For [...] tests of hybrid (webview-based) apps, Appium comes bundled with another automation backend called Selendroid.

In order to configure `Selendroid`, you need to specify the `automationName` parameter:

> To use Selendroid, all that is required is to slightly change the set of desired capabilities mentioned above, by adding the automationName capability and specifying the Selendroid automation backend.

Comment: I read about `Selendroid` before but I thought it's for Android smaller than 4.3. After setting the `automationName` to `Selendroid` it works like charm. Great! Thank you